# IMetaCollection/IEnumerable freeing memory

Tags: c#, generics

I am using a structure from someone else that inherits from `imetacollection<t>`
i am trying to determine how to dispose of the list.  there is no clear() or dispose().

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When Writing generic class names, wrap them in ` characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net's garbage collector will take care of it.
You don't need to do anything.

`Dispose()` is only used to close an object which uses native resources (eg, a graphics device context).
For normal objects, it is unnecessary and non-existent.

Comment: No.. The Problem is I am getting an OutOfMemoryException.. I watch my memorry eat away on my machine.  So GC is not taking care of it.  Somehow the site removed my <> T on the imetacollection... so it's using generics..

Comment: That means that you have a reference to it somewhere.  Set that reference to `null`.